# Running a cronjob as www-data

Tags: cron, nginx

My server is running on Ubuntu and nginx. My problem concerns **Cron**, I'd like to start it (crontab) using a file - *cron.txt*, its content:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/test.php >> /var/log/cron.log
```

If I run it using a command: `crontab /var/www/html/cron.txt`, it works perfectly, script *test.php* is being executed. But when I do the same but using a PHP script (executing via browser): `exec('crontab /var/www/html/cron.txt');`, it doesn't work.

Checking current cronjob by command: `crontab -l -u www-data`, the line from the file appears, but Cron does not do its job. Maybe it's related to some permission issues? Because it only works by executing as a root. Is there a way to force Cron to do www-data's tasks as well?

Answer (score 3):

Please use `/etc/crontab`. That method of doing cron jobs allows you to add a user name to the task. It will look like this:

```
* * * * * www-data /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/test.php >> /var/log/cron.log
```

You can do `nano /etc/crontab` and add the line to the file.

> But when I do the same but using a PHP script (executing via browser): exec('crontab /var/www/html/cron.txt');, it doesn't work.

If that does not work you probably have another problem than "crontab" usage. For instance: do you not need to redirect? (ie. use `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` at the end of your exec command?).

Comment: Awww, you beat me to the actual answer.  Mine was a comment, but your's much better!  +1  =)

Comment: @Terrance been there done that ;=)

Comment: Honestly speaking I don't know what it means (`> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &`), could you explain a little? You mean something like that: `exec('crontab /var/www/html/cron.txt > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');`?

Comment: That would redirect output and errors to "/dev/null". And the "&" detaches the command from the original thread. You really should know about these though.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what I wanted, everything about the code in my initial post is ok, the only thing I should've known is that the www-data user is not allowed to write in `/var/log`, so I had no output there. And in addition, in my PHP script I was trying to create a file and write something into it, to do is, the absolute path is required, so it should look like:

```
dirname(__FILE__) . '/myfile.txt';
```

After these changes, everything works as expected.